# React-native : OnLongPress is not working in Tablet device(Both in android & ios)

Tags: react-native

I have list of items in a `FlatList` and each item is wrapped with `TouchableOpacity` in which both `onPress` and `onLongPress` are implemented.

```
<TouchableOpacity style={Styles.tabletStyle.listRowStyle} onPress={() => this.onRowClick(item)} onLongPress={(event) => this.onContextMenuOpen(event, item)}}>
    <Text>Render Something</Text>               
</TouchableOpacity>
```

`onLongPress` is working as expected in mobiles but not in tablet. This is happening in both `android` and `ios` tablets and in emulator and real devices. Some times when the list item is hold for long time `onPress` is getting initiated.

### Environment

```
targetSdkVersion 26
Machine OS is Ubuntu
react-native: 0.52.2
Tablet OS is Nougat & ios 12.1
```

Can anybody help in this regard?

Comment: Check your click area that should be bigger touch area to handle click listener.

Comment: @QuokMoon `Touchable` area is big enough. I have even checked an icon `size: 100` and a card item with `height: 40` and  `width: 100%`. But still not working